# In SvelteKit, what's the difference between +page.js, +page.server.js and +page.svelte?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I can't make sense of the docs on this at all.

I'm *assuming*:

- `+page.server.js` = code that runs server side (fetching data from db etc.)
- `+page.js` = code that runs client side (dynamic stuff in the browser)
- `+page.svelte` = the main front end.

As a specific example, I have a `data.user.startdate` prop in my layout that I want to manipulate so I can display the difference between now and start date.

+page.svelte can access this no problem here:

```
<script>
 export let data;
</script>
```

And I *could* just manipulate the data here, however I'm assuming best practice would be to do this in `+page.js`

But `+page.js` seemingly have no equivalent way to access the data prop, without some sort of parent inherit, which is messy compared to `+page.svelte`

I believe the main issue is likely my understanding of the purpose of the sveltekit files, hence the question is about the framework files.

*As a side note, why the `+` signs, and what's best practice in searching files in VS Code, as all route files are named the same!*

Comment: sorry for forwarding out, but have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ampDDmT3TU0 (Learn How Data Flows In Your SvelteKit App)

Comment: > why the + signs, and what's best practice in searching files in VS Code, as all route files are named the same! – I'd say: in vscode, keep open only the files you need and enable path breadcrumbs. And divide them on different tabs. Once you get it, the + sign is an anchor. You can't go wrong. You can also configure vscode to show directories first and files following, and other vscode tweaks. hth

Comment: About your question, it can be answered under different perspectives. one of them is: `+page.server.ts` is server side only, `+page.ts` is "universal" (executed on server side and on client), `+page.svelte` only client. Read again [the official routing docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing), have a look at the video I told the link and eventually ask again and someone (maybe me) will write a proper answer. <3

Answer (score 4):

`+` is used to mark files reserved by svelteKit to answer why `+` specifically for the same reason why `/` is used for commands just because they needed to use some uncommon symbole in the beginning of the name.

`+page.server.js` The following file is run on the server so it is used to fetch data from some API which requires an API key and then you just send the data to the client, that way your API key wouldn't be exposed to the client.

`+page.js` is just a file where you can have js for the page, so you might want to move some function that has a lot of logic and is a bit too big in there. (So you will most likely not have this file for every page)

`+page.svelte` is where your frontend is, so your HTML styles and js.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the details provided by @Laycookie I would add that while `+page.js` and the content of the `<script>` tag inside `+page.svelte` are both client side Javascript, there is an important difference regarding certain reserved statements that only work inside `+page.js`.

For example, when building a static site, to mark a route to be prerendered, the documentation points you to include this statement:

```js
export const prerender = true;
```

which will only work inside the `.js` and not the corresponding `.svelte` file (presumably because you can't export injected JS?). **So, watch out for the file extensions in the documentation and error message.**

See also [this article](https://dev.to/robertobutti/how-to-start-building-your-static-website-with-svelte-and-tailwindcss-hbk) on other statements that only work in the `.js` file.